# How to embed images to pandas DataFrame and show in flask webpage

Tags: python, html, image, pandas, flask

I want to show a table with a column of images and rest columns are text, to Flask pages. I can display table with images in jupyter notebook. But I cannot export as html code that can be embedded to flask to show the images. Instead, I saw just text `<img src="http://url.to.image.png"/>`.

```
    import pandas as pd
    from IPython.display import Image, HTML
    df['IMAGE'] = df['IMGLINK'].apply(lambda x: '<img src="{}"/>'.format(x) if x else '')
    pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
    HTML(df.to_html(escape=False))
```

In my Flask app.py code, I have the following:

```
    @app.route('/result', methods=['POST'])
    def result():
        pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth',-1)
        df = pd.read_csv('DATA_1.csv')
        df['IMAGE'] = df['IMGLINK'].apply(lambda x: '<img src="{}"/>'.format(x) if x else '')
        df_html = dfresult.to_html(index=False)#line_width=60, col_space=70
        return render_template('result.html', datatable=df_html)
```

In my result.html, I have line `{{ datatable | safe }}`.

Comment: Why do you need to use pandas for this?

Comment: Since I have my data stored in pandas and df.to_html() gives most of what I need except for showing image in flask html.

Answer (score 0):

Image is not rendering, because the markup is encoded as text, not as html
If you looking to render image from dataframe, you need to use Markup().unescape() method.

```py
html = Markup(dataframeName.to_html(classes='data')).unescape()
```

This will convert &lt to < and likewise other symbols to tags.

If you want to see, why this is happening, you can F12 in chrome, select tag and right click > edit as html, you will see that your image tag is looking something like:
`&lt;img src='url_path'&gt;`
however, it should look like:  `<img src='url_path'>`